# MQ explorer hangs at startup

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mq

MQ explorer V9.1 hangs at startup. can someone provide any insights on how to fix the issue?
Sometimes it loads perfectly.
I have tried running with traces , but couldn't see any errors.

The error when its hangs is as printed on from console is

```
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
Windows_ExceptionCode=c0000139 J9Generic_Signal=00000004 
.......
```

Comment: Have you contacted support?

Comment: not contacted support. is this something related to an issue in the V9.1 ?

Comment: 9.1 is no longer supported,  have you tried with a supported version (9.2 or 9.3)?

Answer (score 0):

The end of service date for IBM MQ v9.1 was September 30, 2023. See:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/announcement-end-support-ibm-mq-910-lts-and-ibm-mq-91x-cd

You should un-install MQ Explorer v9.1, then download and install [MQ Explorer](https://ibm.biz/mqexplorer) v9.3 because you won't get any support from IBM for a release that is no longer supported.

---

Update: January 9, 2024.

You need to provide more information (update your question).

- What version/release of Windows are you using?
- Are you running MQ Explorer on a PC/laptop or server?
- Are you running MQ Explorer in a VM or container?
- Where did you install MQ Explorer?
- Do you have anything in the MQ Explorer "dropins" folder/directory?
- Do you have any other JDK or JRE in your PATH environment variable?
- Are you running it on a PC/laptop with a very limited amount of memory?

Comment: same error with V9.3 explorer as well

Comment: See my updates in my answer.

Comment: thanks Roger ,i managed to fix it in a different way

Comment: You should post how you fixed it! (for future users who have the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to offending paths from other MQ server installations in the PATH variable. Had to make the PATH variable empty in the command prompt and just launch the MQexplorer.exe from the installed path on the same command terminal.